# How 'pass by value slice' and 'the underlying array' behaves in Golang?

Tags: arrays, go

I am trying to implement a depth first search in GO and I am facing below issue.

In GO whenever we pass a slice to a function it should create a new slice header as GO is pass by value language but at the same time newly created slice should point to the same underlying array to which previous slice was pointing.

But Looks like in my depth first search function, passed slice is not pointing to the same array.

As we can see in below mentioned code I am calling depth first traverse function recursively with node and slice as parameters where slice stores the value for each visited node. After traversing entire tree I should get all the nodes in the slice but the slice was empty.

```
func (b *BinarySearchTree) DFSInOrder(node *Node, list []int) {

    if node.Left != nil {
        b.DFSInOrder(node.Left, list)
    }

    list = append(list, node.Value)

    if node.Right != nil {
        b.DFSInOrder(node.Right, list)
    }
}

func main() {
    //...
    //BinarySearchTree creation code
    //...
    
    var list []int
    b.DFSInOrder(b.Root, list)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("List after traversing:", list)
}
```

Ideally in each recursive call even if it is creating new slice it should update the same underlying array and finally original slice should have all the nodes but it was empty.

Can some one please explain why this is happening?

Please find full code for more details here: https://play.golang.com/p/PCrADg3zYV8 
Check function at line 51.

Note: If I pass slice pointer`(list *[]int)` then it works fine.

Comment: You're using `append` which will allocate a new array once the `cap` of the old array is insufficient.

Comment: Please include the relevant code *in the body of your question*. Use external links only for additional context. Links can break.

Comment: And note that you don't have to use a pointer, just like `append` doesn't, instead have your method return the new slice: https://play.golang.com/p/o24uEH5oRG2. But it's up to you, both options are fine. And also note that if your original assumption about slices and their underlying arrays was correct then having `append` return the new slice would be foolish.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for pointing out correctly that `append` is creating new array.

Comment: @Adrian As per your suggestion added relevant code in the question body.

Comment: @Yugendra there's one more flaw in your original approach. The slice header contains not only the pointer to an element in the underlying array but also the length and the capacity of the slice, and every time the slice is passed around these 3 values get copied. This means that even if, in your playground example, you allocate a large enough array for the initial `list` variable so that `append` will not have to allocate a new one, as you pass it around the len gets copied, it is *not* automatically modified in every single copy of the slice. https://play.golang.com/p/gHXUscM-P2H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example [go playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/OIbY6ExyaRa). `append` is allocating a new slice, and saving the new slice to the value, not the reference. You are correct, you don't need to pass a slice by reference to modify the underlying elements which is what the `editSlice` function does in my example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    slice := []int{10, 20}
    appendSlice(slice)
    fmt.Println("slice after append ", slice)

    editSlice(slice)
    fmt.Println("slice after edit ", slice)
}

func appendSlice(s []int) {
    s = append(s, s[0])
    fmt.Println("the appended slice ", s)
}

func editSlice(s []int) {
    s[0] = s[0] * 2
}
```

If you still want to use the `append` syntax in your code, I updated it to pass and modify the slice by reference ([go playground](https://play.golang.com/p/6tAGl4zDdvy)).