# modify slice in function

Tags: go

I noticed today that the *address* of a slice does not change when I pass slice by *value*, so in that case I would expect the slice in `main()` to have the same backing array as the slice inside the function.

BUT that cannot be, because the contents of the slice are different in the function vs in main after function return.

Here is sample code to demonstrate (golang 1.16), where append() DOES NOT CREATE a new object (because I set the capacity to avoid that):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// must use pointer since modifying the slice
func modSlice(mySlice *[]string) {
    *mySlice = append(*mySlice, "abc")
    fmt.Printf("In modSlice(): %p %v\n", *mySlice, len(*mySlice))
}

// this ones shows same address for mySlice as in main!
func modSliceFail(mySlice []string) {
    mySlice = append(mySlice, "ABC")
    fmt.Printf("In modSliceFail(): %p %v\n", mySlice, len(mySlice))
}

func main() {
    mySlice := make([]string, 0, 100)
    fmt.Printf("In main() before: %p %v\n\n", mySlice, len(mySlice))

    modSlice(&mySlice)
    fmt.Printf("In main() after modSlice(pointer to slice): %p %v\n\n", mySlice, len(mySlice))

    modSliceFail(mySlice)
    fmt.Printf("In main() after modSliceFail(): %p %v\n\n", mySlice, len(mySlice))
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
In main() before: 0xc000115500 0

In modSlice(): 0xc000115500 1
In main() after modSlice(pointer to slice): 0xc000115500 1

In modSliceFail(): 0xc000115500 2
In main() after modSliceFail(): 0xc000115500 1
```

Notice how the pointer to the slice is the same throughout. How is this possible, if the slice is copied by value in the case of `modSliceFail()`?

**Edit**:
The 2 answers so far do not answer my question. I understand how append works and that if the capacity is insufficient, a new object will be returned. That's why I set the capacity in the example code above, so this would not happen. The issue is that pointer inside the fail function is same as in main, both before append (showing the function is using not just the same slice header, but the same slice object) and after append (showing again the object, which is not the case of capacity is 1).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're seeing the pointer to the slice when printed with %p but you're passing around a reference or value to the slice header depending on the function in your example. You don't actually need to pass a reference to modify a slice, but you do need to pass a reference when using `append` because in some cases calls to `append` will allocate a new slice when additional capacity is needed, and the slice header will need to be updated to reflect the pointer to the newly allocated slice. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68288325/13906951) may illustrate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read carefully my question, it is about pointers I'm *expecting to be different* but instead output shows them to be the same, whereas we know they should be different. The answers all focus on the typical other question of why pointers can be different after slice append() etc.

The correct answer is that `%p` on a slice does not print the address of slice, it prints the address of the first element of slice, ie of its backing array (see https://pkg.go.dev/fmt?utm_source=gopls#pkg-overview).

So my sample code was not actually printing what I thought it was. It's admittedly a silly mistake. If I use `%p` on the address of slice instead of slice itself, everything makes sense.

Here is paired down code that shows this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func modSliceFail(mySlice []string) {
    fmt.Println("\nIn modSlice():")
    fmt.Printf("%50v: %p    %p\n", "mySlice header address, backend array address", &mySlice, mySlice)
    fmt.Printf("%50v\n", "(header different from main, same backing array)")
}

func main() {
    mySlice := make([]string, 0)
    fmt.Println("INIT:")
    fmt.Printf("%50v: %p    %p\n", "mySlice header address, backend array address", &mySlice, mySlice)

    modSliceFail(mySlice)
}
```

outputs

```
INIT:
     mySlice header address, backend array address: 0xc00000c030    0xc000010240

In modSlice():
     mySlice header address, backend array address: 0xc00000c060    0xc000010240
  (header different from main, same backing array)
```

In my original post, I was printing the address of backing array (2nd column in the below output), not that of slice.

Answer (score 2):

Other answer is great, I just wanted to summarize some of the points on this
topic. If the argument is a slice, you can edit but not append, regardless of
capacity. If the argument is a pointer, you can edit and append. Example:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func oneTwo(b []byte) {
   b[0] = 1
   b = append(b, 2)
}

func threeFour(b *[]byte) {
   (*b)[0] = 3
   *b = append(*b, 4)
}

func main() {
   b := make([]byte, 1, 9)
   oneTwo(b)
   fmt.Println(b) // [1]
   threeFour(&b)
   fmt.Println(b) // [3 4]
}
```

Comment: I already know that, that is not my question, please have a look at my edit.

Answer (score -1):

[Appending onto a slice](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15) may return a *new* slice if it needs to reallocate a backing array.

[This example](https://play.golang.org/p/f3D7sAt11R6) in the playground:

```golang
func printSlice(desc string, s []int) {
    if cap(s) == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%s:\tempty\n", desc)
        return
    }
    full := s[:cap(s)]
    fmt.Printf("%s:\tlen=%d,\tcap=%d,\tarray=%v @ %p,\tslice=%v\n",
        desc, len(s), cap(s), full, &full[0], s)
}

func main() {
    arr := [10]int{}

    s := arr[:0]
    printSlice("start", s)

    // There is plenty of room for 5 elements
    s = append(s, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    printSlice("first 5", s)

    // and just enough room  for 5 more, so the backing array is reused
    s = append(s, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
    printSlice("second 5", s)

    // but an entirely new slice with a different array is returned once it can't fit
    s = append(s, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
    printSlice("third 5", s)
}
```

will print:

```
start:      len=0,  cap=10, array=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]                     @ 0xc0000be000, slice=[]
first 5:    len=5,  cap=10, array=[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]                     @ 0xc0000be000, slice=[1 1 1 1 1]
second 5:   len=10, cap=10, array=[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]                     @ 0xc0000be000, slice=[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]
third 5:    len=15, cap=20, array=[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0] @ 0xc0000c4000, slice=[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3]
```

This is why the `append` builtin returns a slice instead of modifying it in place: in order to get the *new* slice after it is grown, you have to replace the value that was given to `append`.

In your code, when you say

```golang
    *mySlice = append(*mySlice, "abc")
```

you are overwriting the slice value, so the caller is able to observe the result of the append.  However, when you say

```golang
    mySlice = append(mySlice, "ABC")
```

that is only overwriting a local variable, so the caller can't see the new slice.  You will likely want to write something like

```
func modSliceFailFixed(mySlice []string) []string {
    mySlice = append(mySlice, "ABC")
    return mySlice
}
// call like:
s = modSliceFailFixed(s)
```

if you need to have a function that might require changing the dimensions of a slice.

Comment: I already know that, that is not my question, please have a look at my edit.